# How many Tesla can stop 1 Sievert?

Tags: magnetic-fields, radiation, inductance, space

The SI unit of Magnetic field is Tesla. The magnetic field of Earth blocks all the radiation coming from space which is measured in Sievert. I'm designing a solenoid that can counter the radiation with magnetic field. So is there any relation between how many Tesla of magnetic field is needed to stop 1 sievert?

Comment: To be more precise, the magnetic field of Earth _diverts charged particles._ It doesn't stop radiation.

Comment: Does it divert the charged particles toward poles or reflect them back into space?

Comment: My layman's understanding is that charged particles start to spiral in the earth's magnetic field and divert towards the magnetic poles where they get a bigger chance to enter the atmosphere. That's the cause of [Aurora Borealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora) near the north pole. There is also an Aurora Australis near the south pole.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: It does if the radiation are beta particles (charged electrons). But, in general, gamma rays (high energy photons) are not diverted by Earth's magnetic field.

Comment: @MrQ, Correct, because gamma photons are not charged particles.